# Timeout resolving sbt-plugin

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I'm trying to run a simple play-scala example, but I've some problem launching activator because I have a lot of connection timeout. I've only created the application with activator and tried to launch it. No development or custom configuration. I'm using play 2.4.2.

It seems that many of the dependencies that it tries to resolve do not exist: if I try to open the url in browser I obtain only "The request path was not found".
Examples are the following:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/rjs/2.1.15/ivys/ivy.xml

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-rjs/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml

This behaviour wastes a lot of time without any value. Is it possible to avoid non-existing path or minimize connection timeout time?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: Would the same happen for a newer version of Play?

Comment: I've not tried yet

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, please try the latest version of Play.
As of 2018, it's 2.6.16.